# Create ruby function from string

Tags: ruby

I have the body of a ruby function as a string like

```
s = "x + 1"
```

I would like to do something like

```
fn = make_function(:x, s)
y = fn(10) # returns 11
```

What is the best way to achieve something like this?

Note that I'd rather not just keep eval'ing the string for each function call

Comment: The syntax you are looking for doesn't work with a function, it only works with a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will eval the string once to define the function.

```
eval ['def fn(x)', s, 'end'].join("\n")
```

Here's something like your desired `make_function`

```
def make_function(klass, name, args, body)
  args = [ args ].flatten.map(&:to_s).join(', ')
  klass.class_eval ["def #{name} (#{args})", body, 'end'].join("\n")
end


irb> make_function(Object,:foo,[:x],'x*2')
=> nil
irb> foo(10)
=> 20
irb> foo(1.3)
=> 2.6
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval` a `Proc`!

```
def make_function(arguments, body)
    eval "Proc.new { |#{arguments}
              #{body}
          }"
end

f = make_function :x, 'x + 1'

puts f.call 10 # 11
puts f.call 21 # 22
```

Comment: This doesn't quite make a function in the way the OP asked. The syntax for calling a lambda is different than an ordinary method.

Answer (score 0):

You really DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS.  But it works as you wanted nevertheless.

```
module Kernel
  def make_function(*args, string)
    method_name = args.shift
    parameters = args


    args_string = parameters.map{|p| p.to_s}.join(",")

    instance_eval <<-RUBY 
      def #{method_name}(#{args_string})
        #{string}
      end 
    RUBY
  end
end

s = "x + 1"

make_function(:fn,:x,s)
puts fn(1) #=> 2

s2 = "x + y"
make_function(:foo,:x, :y,s2)
puts foo(1,5) #=> 2
```